How can I add a tmpfs mount to a GKE cluster?
I have little experience with GKE but I need to deploy an ephemeral tmpfs mount to my cluster. It does not need to be shared, just a file system to interact with temporarily. How can I do this in the console or through a .yaml file?

You can mount a tmpfs volume to a Pod (sic.) using emptyDir with its medium field set to "Memory". Please understand the caveats as described in the link.

You can deploy pod with tmpfs ephemeral volume using this yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-eph-volume
spec:
  containers:
    - image: registry.k8s.io/test-webserver
      name: test-container
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp/tmpfs
          name: tmpfs-volume
  volumes:
    - name: tmpfs-volume
      emptyDir:
        medium: "Memory"
        sizeLimit: "1Gi"

To apply it using console:
kubectl apply -f <your-yaml-file-name>

